# Android Studio: TableRow after ScrollView not appearing

Tags: xml, android-studio

I am trying to create a table with a fixed first and last row to be fixed and the table in between to be scrollable. My code thus far is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/last_row"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include layout="@layout/first_row" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/scoreCardTable"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:isScrollContainer="true" />
    </ScrollView>

    <include layout="@layout/last_row" />
</TableLayout>
```

layout/first_row contains:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableRow xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/first_row"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <!-- Headers for Score card -->
    <TextView
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:padding="3dip"
        android:text="@string/hole" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:text="@string/par"
        android:padding="3dip" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_column="3"
        android:text="@string/distance"
        android:padding="3dip" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_column="4"
        android:text="@string/score"
        android:padding="3dip" />
</TableRow>
```

and layout/last_row contains:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableRow xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/first_row"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/par_total"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:padding="3dip"
        android:text="PAR" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/distance_total"
        android:layout_column="3"
        android:padding="3dip"
        android:text="DISTANCE" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/score_total"
        android:layout_column="4"
        android:padding="3dip"
        android:text="SCORE" />
</TableRow>
```

Currently, the first row is fixed, the body is scrollable, but the last row does not appear at all. I don't want the first and last row to be a header or footer because I plan to have headers and footers as well later on. Does anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

A TableLayout inherits from LinearLayout which requires you to apply layout weights so the child views which are set to wrap their content don't push out the others which is likely what is happening there.
Best would be to try to set the weights of the head and footer items to 0.5 and the scroll layout to 0 and also its height to 0dp for reasons specific to how Android's LinearLayout is resolving the weighted views.

Comment: Unfortunately that solution just lead to the scroll view's content not appearing. Only setting the weights to your specifications produces the same result described in my post. Not sure how to pursue this solution further / if I did something wrong while implementing it.

Comment: Changing both Table Rows, and Scroll View layout_height to 0px and layout_weight to 1 resolved the issue.